# Windows XP covered up by Windows 7 Bootloader

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, bootloader

I have two hard drives in my system, one for Windows 7  and one for Windows XP. I had to reinstall Windows 7, and after the re-install, the Windows 7 boot loader started showing up. This did not show up before the re-install.

I usually use Windows XP for defaults and go into the BIOS boot menu to boot to Windows 7. Now, whenever I try to boot to Windows XP—through both boot menu and default—Windows 7 boot loader takes over and boots straight to Windows 7. This happens even when I select the Windows XP hard drive and there appears to be no Windows XP option in the boot loader.

**EDIT:** I have tried adding a menu option via [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/), but an error shows up. Also, I can boot into Windows 7 just fine. The error is:

Windows failed to start! A recent hardware or software change might have caused the problem.

File: \NST\ntldr
Status: 0xc000000f
Info: Selected entry could not be loaded because application is missing or corrupt

Comment: You need to provide the error..